# gawk error when compiling libgpg-error in crossdev armv7a environment

Tags: gentoo, crossdev

I have gentoo `~amd64` installed
and I'm trying to create a crossdev environment for `armv7a-hardfloat-linux-gnueabi`.

my CFLAGS are `CCFLAGS="-O2 -pipe -fomit-frame-pointer".

when I try to compile the base system, it tries to compile `libgpg-error` and fails with:

```
gawk: fatal: cannot use gawk builtin `namespace' as variable
```

how do I resolve this to continue and build my crossdev environment ?

I tried downgrading gawk from 5 to 4 but the results are the same.

thanks

Comment: Don’t you need to show some code or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same problem on my side:

> "namespace" name is not acceptable by gawk-5.0

try:

```
sed -i                                                  \
  -e "s/namespace/varerrno/g"                           \
  src/{Makefile.am,mkstrtable.awk}
```

Before doing `./autogen.sh` or/and `./configure`

Hoping that help.

Comment: You, sir, solved my problem within a google query and 5 seconds of work.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be a typo?

Change "libpgp-error" to "libgpg-error".

Even one of the blue buttons has label "libgpg-error"

Comment: I wrote it here with a typo, corrected the text. thanks